# Sharing the component to multiple applications

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 react projects. I have written as admin project and user project. Now I need some admin menus in the user project so that I have imported that component from admin project. I am getting the error that "Outside src module not allowed." I don't know how to fix this project.

Could you please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance

```
./src/App.js
Module not found: You attempted to import /home/assistanz/Projects/React/yarn/user/src/customer which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
```

Comment: The bundler bundles the files only in `src` folder. Otherwise user project will contains all the code from the admin project too. There are some ways you can share code between projects. For example, you can create another project that contains the relevant code and both of the projects will consume it as npm package.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another project that includes only shared components (new git repository or npm package). Then you would treat it as an external library, add it into your package.json and import components from within into your projects. Think of it as you think of any external library for UI purposes (eg. Material UI).

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that your all components are must be in **public/src** directory of your project. So 
put your admin project's components in the src directory of user project and then import them in your project.

I hope this will help you.